# Can I put a QuickOffice File shortcut on my home screen?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, google-drive

I have a document in Google Drive that I am managing through QuickOffice, which is keeping a local copy of the file on my Galaxy S3. I would like to place a shortcut to this document on my home screen, but for the life of me, I can't find the local file. I'm assuming QuickOffice hides or encrypts it so that other apps can't mess with it, but that means I can't find it to make a shortcut.

It is important that this file remain in Google Drive, so I can't just create a local copy of the file and shortcut it through a file manager like ES File Explorer. If I could locate the local copy I would do this, but as I said, I can't find it.

So, my question has two parts:

1. Do you know where QuickOffice stores local copies of Google Drive files?

and/or

1. Is it possible to place a shortcut to a Google Drive file on my home screen?

---

*QuickOffice 6.1.183 | Android 4.1.1 | Samsung S3 1747MVLDLK4*

Answer (score 1):

Open your app drawer and jump to the Widgets section. Swipe until you get to "Drive Shortcut". Long-press and drop on your desktop. Choose the account to use (if necessary) then select the document.